# Should you use log4net for small to mid-sized projects?

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I just got introduced to log4net and its abilities. For starters I'm currently working on a small project. We need to log errors,warnings etc to a file and also send an email to all developers involved about any Fatal errors. Is log4net an overkill for a small project thats got about 10 classes that require the logging functions? Are there any benefits of using log4net in the long run? We were initially going to just use FileIO manipulations and Mail functions to achieve the same.

Comment: We can't answer this. What is the alternative? No logging? Building a logging framework yourself? Using a more "lightweight" logger, whatever that may be (I sense from your question that you find log4net "overkill")? List all your requirements, find out the capabilities of each alternative and choose the one that best fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on this question is primarily opinion-based, some reasons to use a logging framework from the start:

- Standard way of logging
- Easy configuration
- Small projects will grow, if you do it right from the start, there is no later rework needed
- Using a logging framework will not cost you more time than writing your own. It will probably safe time. For example log4net will never crash your program when logging fails. Your own framework might interact with your business logic and gives you unexpected results.